# Copy or Duplicate a list with the same data

Tags: sharepoint-server, list

I have a silly question and I hope someone could point me in the right direction.

I have a giant list with all my fields plus some lookup columns etc. that list is generally used by the production department. those guys they are responsible to update the list and keep the record. etc. Now I have the quality department those guys they want to use the same list but some values in that list. Is there any way to have another list the is been feed by the production list? I don't want that the quality guys change records etc only see the data coming from the production list.

And also, if it is possible to make this, is there any way to have in the quality list a lookup columns that concatenate values from the production list?

Thanks in advance for any response.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

That is not a silly question. It's actually a good idea not to duplicate data if it's being used as a lookup for more than one department. What version of SharePoint are you using? Is this data on the same farm? Same site / site collection or different? The answer would depend on where the source and target sites are... Even if they are on different farms, you may be able to do something with REST (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints), or if you have Nintex, some kind of a workflow, possibly SP2013 workflow. HTH

Comment: Thank you! :-) Share point online O365. And all the list are in the same site

Answer (score 0):

You could create a lookup column in the quality department list to show data in the production department list.

1.Production department list.

[image]

2.Quality department list

[image]

3.Lookup column.

[image]

4.Result.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will check this

Comment: Hi, thank you very much it is working!!! :-)

Comment: If the answer is helpful, you can accept it as answer.